# Unit conversion is not simplifying units

Tags: units

I'm running into what looks like an error.

```
<< PhysicalConstants`;
fieldGradient = Quantity[10,  "Teslas"/"Meters"] (* Tesla/meter *)
Energy = Quantity[100, "MegaElectronVolts"]
K = fieldGradient*SpeedOfLight*ElectronCharge/Energy (* m^-2 *)
```

K should have the units of meters^-2, but Mathematica insists on the output:

```
(Coulomb Meter (Quantity[4.8032*10^-12, ("Teslas")/("Megaelectronvolts" "Meters")]))/Second
```

Am I using the Units wrong here? This is my first try at using the Units package in Mathematica 9.

Comment: Please define `SpeedOfLight` and `ElectronCharge` such that the example is self-contained.

Comment: Done, sorry, I forgot the PhysicalConstants package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v10, the `PhysicalConstants` package isn't required.

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

Use `UnitConvert` to put all units into SI units

```
fieldGradient = UnitConvert[Quantity[10, "Tesla/Meter"]];

Energy = UnitConvert[Quantity[100, "MegaElectronVolts"]];

K = fieldGradient*
  UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]]*
  UnitConvert[Quantity["ElectronCharge"]]/
   Energy
```

> Quantity[29.97925, 1/("Meters")^2]

or

```
fieldGradient = Quantity[10, "Tesla/Meter"];

Energy = Quantity[100, "MegaElectronVolts"];

K = fieldGradient*
   Quantity["SpeedOfLight"]*
   Quantity["ElectronCharge"]/
    Energy // UnitConvert
```

> Quantity[29.97925, 1/("Meters")^2]

Comment: So it won't convert across unit systems otherwise?

Comment: I assume that if you give it mixed units that it doesn't try to guess what unit system you want and leaves the units as is. Since you stated that you expect the output in 1/meters^2 then SI is presumably what you what. That is the default for `UnitConvert`. However, you could use `//UnitConvert[#,"Imperial"]&` and get the output in `1/Inches^2`.